# Using TCP Westwood protocol compilation error

Tags: networking, tcp, tcl, ns2

**Hi Guys,**
I'm working with a friend on network protocol simulation with ns-2,I'm new to this environment and facing some difficulties.

The one tutorial I used did this for the Westwood protocol, so I'll include my errors for that one just because it's a little simpler.

This is the guide I followed: 
http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~nrl/hpi/tcpw/tcpw_ns2/tcp-westwood-ns2.html

**Outline of steps:**

1. Add tcp-westwood.cc & tcp-westwood.h files to tcp folder in
   the main ns2 directory (ns-2.35)
2. Edit the makefile to include tcp-westwood.o file (within the obj_cc variable).
3. Add the appropriate lines to ns-default.tcl file (see link)
4. Recompile (recompile steps: go to ns-2.35 directory; type "./configure"; type
   "make")

**Goal:**
To try out TCP Westwood protocol (a third party protocol source code) in ns-2 to simulate some network scenarios.

**Problem:**
When I run test.tcl using the Reno tcp protocol I get no errors. But when I change the line "set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Reno" to  "set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Westwood" in the test.tcl file, I get the output from the screen shot (see attached).

[I have upload code files here on google drive.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4orcwuF56g1dGpQVENjZmR0ajQ&usp=sharing)

[image]

Any help or tip will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that the code is either not built into the simulator at all, or is not being activated in the interpreter.

Comment: Hi Donal,
Would you give some more explanation or any link for further help,I was only following the tutorial I don't have the clear understanding how these different source code files are meant to work together.